# How to display two graph generated from separate code from “observablehq” on one browser window

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, observablehq

I am new in d3.js.I downloaded two code generating graphs from site “observablehq”. Here are links to codes.

1- [zoomable-area-chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-area-chart)

2-[focus-context](https://observablehq.com/@d3/focus-context)

**I want to display both graphs in the same browser window**. For this, I placed the files in the same directory. Here is html code of zoomable-area-chart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zoomable Area Chart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./inspector.css">
<body>
<script type="module">

import define from "./index.js";
import {Runtime, Library, Inspector} from "./runtime.js";

const runtime = new Runtime();
const main = runtime.module(define, Inspector.into(document.body));

</script>
```

Here is html code of focus-context

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Focus + Context</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inspector1.css">
<body>
<script type="module">

import define from "./index1.js";
import {Runtime, Library, Inspector} from "./runtime1.js";

const runtime = new Runtime();
const main = runtime.module(define, Inspector.into(document.body));

</script>
```

I placed "Focus + Context" "script" in html file of "Zoomable Area Chart" like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zoomable Area Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./inspector.css">
    <body>
    <script type="module">

    import define from "./index.js";
    import {Runtime, Library, Inspector} from "./runtime.js";

    const runtime = new Runtime();
    const main = runtime.module(define, Inspector.into(document.body));

    </script>
    <script type="module">

        import define from "./index1.js";
        import {Runtime, Library, Inspector} from "./runtime1.js";

        const runtime = new Runtime();
        const main = runtime.module(define, Inspector.into(document.body));

    </script>
```

then I ran that html file using "webstorm" into browser. It is not displaying both graphs into the same browser window. It is displaying errors for the first graph and displaying the second graph

[image]

Here is js file for "Zoomable Area Chart"

```
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-area-chart@212
export default function define(runtime, observer) {
  const main = runtime.module();
  const fileAttachments = new Map([["flights.csv",new URL("./files/1171cb24da0255c434c1ff554b4964c39c1253aa9349f2d356a25351acd3579367f92b24366ae5b6c208c9336811489c0a176cbc0cc62e31feff51e294a178fe",import.meta.url)]]);
  main.builtin("FileAttachment", runtime.fileAttachments(name => fileAttachments.get(name)));
  main.variable(observer()).define(["md"], function(md){return(
md`# Zoomable Area Chart

This zoomable time series area chart shows the number of flights per day. The effect of the September 11, 2001 attacks on air travel is evident.`
)});
  main.variable(observer("chart")).define("chart", ["d3","margin","width","height","DOM","area","data","x","xAxis","yAxis","y"], function(d3,margin,width,height,DOM,area,data,x,xAxis,yAxis,y)
{
  const zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 32])
      .extent([[margin.left, 0], [width - margin.right, height]])
      .translateExtent([[margin.left, -Infinity], [width - margin.right, Infinity]])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

  const clip = DOM.uid("clip");

  svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", clip.id)
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", margin.left)
      .attr("y", margin.top)
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
      .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

  const path = svg.append("path")
      .attr("clip-path", clip)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", area(data, x));

  const gx = svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis, x);

  svg.append("g")
      .call(yAxis, y);

  svg.call(zoom)
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.scaleTo, 4, [x(Date.UTC(2001, 8, 1)), 0]);

  function zoomed() {
    const xz = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
    path.attr("d", area(data, xz));
    gx.call(xAxis, xz);
  }

  return svg.node();
}
);
  main.variable(observer("height")).define("height", function(){return(
500
)});
  main.variable(observer("margin")).define("margin", function(){return(
{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30}
)});
  main.variable(observer("x")).define("x", ["d3","data","margin","width"], function(d3,data,margin,width){return(
d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
)});
  main.variable(observer("y")).define("y", ["d3","data","height","margin"], function(d3,data,height,margin){return(
d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
)});
  main.variable(observer("xAxis")).define("xAxis", ["height","margin","d3","width"], function(height,margin,d3,width){return(
(g, x) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))
)});
  main.variable(observer("yAxis")).define("yAxis", ["margin","d3","data"], function(margin,d3,data){return(
(g, y) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text(data.y))
)});
  main.variable(observer("area")).define("area", ["d3","y"], function(d3,y){return(
(data, x) => d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveStepAfter)
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(d => y(d.value))
  (data)
)});
  main.variable(observer("data")).define("data", ["d3","FileAttachment"], async function(d3,FileAttachment){return(
Object.assign(d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("flights.csv").text(), d3.autoType), {y: "Flights"})
)});
  main.variable(observer("d3")).define("d3", ["require"], function(require){return(
require("d3@5")
)});
  return main;
}
```

Here is js file for "Focus + Context"

```
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/focus-context@320
export default function define(runtime, observer) {
  const main = runtime.module();
  const fileAttachments = new Map([["aapl.csv",new URL("./files/de259092d525c13bd10926eaf7add45b15f2771a8b39bc541a5bba1e0206add4880eb1d876be8df469328a85243b7d813a91feb8cc4966de582dc02e5f8609b7",import.meta.url)]]);
  main.builtin("FileAttachment", runtime.fileAttachments(name => fileAttachments.get(name)));
  main.variable(observer()).define(["md"], function(md){return(
md`# Focus + Context

This [area chart](/@d3/area-chart) uses brushing to specify a focused area. Drag the gray region to pan, or brush to zoom. Compare to a [zoomable chart](/@d3/zoomable-area-chart). Data: [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup)`
)});
  main.variable(observer("chart")).define("chart", ["d3","width","height","DOM","margin","data","xAxis","yAxis","area"], function(d3,width,height,DOM,margin,data,xAxis,yAxis,area)
{
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .style("display", "block");

  const clipId = DOM.uid("clip");

  svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", clipId.id)
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", margin.left)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right);

  const gx = svg.append("g");

  const gy = svg.append("g");

  const path = svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", clipId)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue");

  return Object.assign(svg.node(), {
    update(focusX, focusY) {
      gx.call(xAxis, focusX, height);
      gy.call(yAxis, focusY, data.y);
      path.attr("d", area(focusX, focusY));
    }
  });
}
);
  main.variable(observer("viewof focus")).define("viewof focus", ["d3","width","focusHeight","margin","x","xAxis","data","area","y"], function(d3,width,focusHeight,margin,x,xAxis,data,area,y)
{
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, focusHeight])
      .style("display", "block");

  const brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([[margin.left, 0.5], [width - margin.right, focusHeight - margin.bottom + 0.5]])
      .on("brush", brushed)
      .on("end", brushended);

  const defaultSelection = [x(d3.utcYear.offset(x.domain()[1], -1)), x.range()[1]];

  svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis, x, focusHeight);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", area(x, y.copy().range([focusHeight - margin.bottom, 4])));

  const gb = svg.append("g")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, defaultSelection);

  function brushed() {
    if (d3.event.selection) {
      svg.property("value", d3.event.selection.map(x.invert, x).map(d3.utcDay.round));
      svg.dispatch("input");
    }
  }

  function brushended() {
    if (!d3.event.selection) {
      gb.call(brush.move, defaultSelection);
    }
  }

  return svg.node();
}
);
  main.variable(observer("focus")).define("focus", ["Generators", "viewof focus"], (G, _) => G.input(_));
  main.variable(observer()).define(["focus","d3","data","chart","x","y"], function(focus,d3,data,chart,x,y)
{
  const [minX, maxX] = focus;
  const maxY = d3.max(data, d => minX <= d.date && d.date <= maxX ? d.value : NaN);
  chart.update(x.copy().domain(focus), y.copy().domain([0, maxY]));
}
);
  main.variable(observer("data")).define("data", ["d3","FileAttachment"], async function(d3,FileAttachment){return(
Object.assign(d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("aapl.csv").text(), d3.autoType).map(({date, close}) => ({date, value: close})), {y: "↑ Close $"})
)});
  main.variable(observer("area")).define("area", ["d3"], function(d3){return(
(x, y) => d3.area()
    .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(d => y(d.value))
)});
  main.variable(observer("x")).define("x", ["d3","data","margin","width"], function(d3,data,margin,width){return(
d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
)});
  main.variable(observer("y")).define("y", ["d3","data","height","margin"], function(d3,data,height,margin){return(
d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
)});
  main.variable(observer("xAxis")).define("xAxis", ["margin","d3","width"], function(margin,d3,width){return(
(g, x, height) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))
)});
  main.variable(observer("yAxis")).define("yAxis", ["margin","d3"], function(margin,d3){return(
(g, y, title) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".title").data([title]).join("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("x", -margin.left)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(title))
)});
  main.variable(observer("margin")).define("margin", function(){return(
{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40}
)});
  main.variable(observer("height")).define("height", function(){return(
440
)});
  main.variable(observer("focusHeight")).define("focusHeight", function(){return(
100
)});
  main.variable(observer("d3")).define("d3", ["require"], function(require){return(
require("d3@5")
)});
  return main;
}
```

**How I can display both graphs in the same browser window correctly**. You can download the complete project from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cDdyx10vmckdCfMH3bQu710SWCT-lxmN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: are you just trying to present both charts? or are you trying to integrate the two different notebooks?

Comment: yes. I am trying to present both charts in the same browser window and trying to integrate the two different notebooks

Comment: if you're trying to integrate observable notebooks, I recommend you doing that inside observable. you can reuse charts using `import` https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-imports  when you're done with your notebook, then you do the process of export and embed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe is the tag which you can use for call other html pages into your web page

```
<iframe src="index1.html" height="700px"  width="100%" style=" border:none;"></iframe>
```